# Determine initial mouse position in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, position, mouse

How can I determine the initial mouse position? right now I use `onmousemove`, but that sometimes only fires when the mouse is actually moved. same with `onmouseover`.

If I don't move the mouse, I observed the following:

It seems like in IE a `mousemove` event is always fired right at the beginning, in firefox never, and in chrome strange enough if the script is loaded from an online location, but not if it's loaded from my local disk.

The question arose because I want stuff to dangle on the cursor and I want it to hang there right from the start and not suddenly appear/jump after the first interaction.

If the solution will be browser specific, my target is chrome.

In case someone wants to explain to me the strange `mousemove` behavior, this is my test:

```
<html><head>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
window.onload = function(){
    setInterval("document.getElementById('div0').innerHTML = MousePosition.x+' '+MousePosition.y;", 200)
}
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scripterlative.com/files/mousepos.j_s"></script> 
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="mousepos.j_s"></script>--> 

</head><body>   

<div id="div0"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
MousePosition.init();
</script>

</body></html>
```

PS: you do not need to lecture me about the use of innerHTML and `onload`, this is quick and dirty on purpose.

Comment: have you tried dispatching a mouseover event manually onload?

Comment: thanks for that reply, i will try to find out how to do that right now. you should have written that as a proper answer for the email notification, i'm just lucky to read that right now.

Comment: ok, i tried it now, it doesnt work. even though clicking the mouse causes a mousemove event, dispatching a click event manually doesnt.

in case you meant that i should fire that event with the correct coordinates, this just shifts the problem, how do i know the coordinates without catching them from an event?